# Issue with getting new data from http call and automatic reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

In my ionic app I have two services Studies and Collections. Studies makes a http call to get a json object which gets a JSON array object which I iterate through and display on the html page. Here is the studies service:

```
.factory('Studies',function($http,$filter,$q){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get("http://localhost/platform/loginSuccess.json").success(
            function(data){
                // angular.copy(data, studies);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
        );

  return {
    all: function(){
      return deferred.promise;
    }
};
})
```

And here is the controller code:

```
$scope.studies = [];

Studies.all().then(function(data) {
                $scope.x = angular.fromJson(data.allProjects);
                $scope.studies = angular.fromJson($scope.x.list);
            });
```

This is how it is displayed in the html:

```
<div class="feed-item" ng-repeat="study in studies">
        <div class="feed-media">
            <img src="http://www.speedhunters.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Lamborghini-Hurac%C3%A1n-LP610-4-01_N3-1200x800.jpg" class="feed-image">
            <div class="feed-gradient-overlay"></div>
            <a href="#/app/studies/{{study.nodeRef}}"><h4 class="feed-title">{{study.title}}</h4></a>z
        </div>
</div>
```

study.nodeRef is then extracted in the same controller and then fetched to another function that calls another service using the nodeRef.

```
scope.nodeId = $stateParams.studynodeRef;
$scope.collection = [];

Collections.fetchCollection($scope.nodeId).then(function(data){
              $scope.y = angular.fromJson(data.list);
              $scope.collections = angular.fromJson($scope.y[0].collections);
});
```

Here is the collections service:

```
.factory('Collections', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
    return {

        fetchCollection: function(collectionId) {
            var deffered = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/platform/project/fetch.json',
                params: {
                  'nodeRef': collectionId
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                deffered.resolve(data);
            });

            return deffered.promise;
        }

    };
}])
```

Then I iterate through the collections in my menu.html page which is basically a side menu present in all my templates:

```
<ion-list ng-controller="NavigationCtrl" ng-repeat="collection in collections">
      <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="go('app.studies')" class="item item-icon-left brand-base-text-color">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-paper"></i>
            {{collection.name}}
        </ion-item>
```

Now when I click on a study on the studies.html page it redirects to the appropriate #/app/studies/{{study.nodeRef}} however, the side menu doesn't update the collections on the side menu even after I refresh it. Both study and collections service are under the same controller called AppCtrl. How do I get the collections to reload automatically based on appropriate nodeRef of the study?

**Edit:**

Here is the code I have in my app.js file for studies,study and menu(where the iteration for collections is done). As can be seen they all use the same controller called AppCtrl:

```
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/rubyonic/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
    reload: true
  })   

.state('app.studies', {
    url: "/studies",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/rubyonic/studies.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
        reload: true
      }
    }
  })

   .state('app.study', {
    url: "/studies/:studynodeRef",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/rubyonic/overview.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
        reload: true
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: scope.nodeId = $stateParams.studynodeRef; - didn't you miss $ in $scope in this line?

Comment: Oh I must have mistyped that it is $scope.nodeId

Comment: Did it help anything?

Comment: I meant I mistyped it here. It has been $scope.nodeId in my code

Comment: Ok, sorry. Is code fetching collections inside NavigationCtrl? Could paste your controllers here?

Comment: both the controls for studies and collections are injected into AppCtrl I already provided the code for AppCtrl above. NavigationCtrl is added in addition to AppCtrl for collections because I am using g-click="go('app.studies')". I added an edit to the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83487/discussion-between-user1585869-and-keammoort).

Comment: Just a note, you don't need to use $q to return a promise, you can simply return the $http request (it's a promise):

    `fetchCollection: function(collectionId) {
            return $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/platform/project/fetch.json',
                params: {
                  'nodeRef': collectionId
                }
            }).success(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
        }`

Comment: have you tried setting 'cache: false' on your states?